# Snowflake: JSON Data in Array

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

JSON data as below

```
{name : Mike, job : [{name: abc, value: 123},{name: def,value: 456}]}
```

How to retrieve the value of name = abc and def?

**EDIT:(SOLUTION)** Got the solution myself thanks

```
 WITH x AS (
SELECT parse_json('{"name" : "Mike", "job" : [{"name": "abc", "value": "123"},{"name": "def","value": "456"}]}' ) as payload_json)
    select x.payload_json:name,
           job.value:name::varchar as name,
           job.value:value::varchar as value
     from x,
    lateral flatten( input => x.payload_json:job, outer => true) as job;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer myself as below

```
 WITH x AS (
SELECT parse_json('{"name" : "Mike", "job" : [{"name": "abc", "value": "123"},{"name": "def","value": "456"}]}' ) as payload_json)
    select x.payload_json:name,
           job.value:name::varchar as name,
           job.value:value::varchar as value
     from x,
    lateral flatten( input => x.payload_json:job, outer => true) as job;
```

Comment: Feel free to tag your own answer as the correct one!